# How to upload video and audio file and save folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 <?php    
    public function videoupld()
    {
       $this->load->helper('string');
       $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/upload/video'; # check path is correct
       $config['max_size'] = '102400000';
       $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp4'; # add video extenstion on here
       $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
       $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
       $video_name =$_FILES['video_image']['name'];`
       $config['file_name'] = $video_name;
       $this->load->library('upload', $config);  
       $this->upload->initialize($config);    
       if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('video_image'))
       {
            echo 'fail';
            return;
            //redirect('Admin/video_upload');
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            $url = 'assets/upload/video'.$video_name;
            $this->Admin_model->videoupld($url);
            redirect('Admin/video_upload');
        }    
    }        
?>
```

**model**

```
    public function videoupld($url)
    {
      $title = $this->input->post('video_image');
      //$details = $this->input->post('details');
      //$type = $this->input->post('gallery');    
      $data = array(
        'title'  => $title,
        'url' => $url,       
        //'category'  => $type`
      );
      $this->db->insert('videoss', $data);          
    }
```

Comment: what is the error? what are you using?

Comment: You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: controllers/Admin.php

Line Number: 142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $uploaded = $this -> upload -> do_upload('video_image');

//here you will receive the object that you uploaded

// you will test if the file exist if yes the variable $file will recieve the full path
            if ($uploaded) {
                if ($data['file_ppt'] != '') {

                    $file = 'uploads/ppt/' . $data['file_ppt']; //full path


                    if (file_exists($file)) {
                        unlink($file);
                    }
                }
            }
         //if file uploaded
         //$save['file_ppt'] will have the name of the file uploaded
             if ($uploaded) {
            $file_ppt = $this -> upload -> data();
            $save['file_ppt'] = $file_ppt['file_name'];
               }
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: controllers/Admin.php

Line Number: 98

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\onemovie\application\controllers\Admin.php
Line: 98
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\onemovie\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Unknown column 'file_ppt' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `videoss` (`file_ppt`) VALUES ('20160724_2053251.mp4')

Comment: can you write me the fields in your table in database

Comment: SELECT `video_id`, `title`, `url` FROM `videoss`

Comment: <form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Admin/videoupld" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><div class="form-group"><label>Video Name</label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter VideoName" class="form-control" name="videoname" id="videoname"><div class="form-group <label>Video Image</label><input type="file" class="form-control" name="video_image" id="video_image"></div> <div class="text-center"><button  type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"   >Submit</button>  </div>
                            </form>

Comment: thank you sir succesfully upload sir thank you so munch sir

Comment: how to add progress bar sir video uploading

Comment: try to add an animate picture (gif) when you click in button

Comment: sir I try to upload video and image in CodeIgniter simultaneously but only the image or video is uploaded

Comment: put this in the view   <input name="file_ppt[]" id="file_ppt" type="file" multiple="" />

Comment: if ($uploaded) {
            $file_ppt = $this -> upload ->data();
            //$save['url'] = $file_ppt['file_name'];
   $save=array(
   'title'=>$this->input->post('videoname'),
   'url'=>$file_ppt['file_name'],
   'image'=>$_FILES['video_image']['name'],
     );
   
      }
        $file =$_FILES['video_image']['tmp_name'];
         $name1=$_FILES['video_image']['name'];
          $type=$_FILES['video_image']['type'];
         $size=$_FILES['video_image']['size']; 
  move_uploaded_file($file,'./assets/upload/video/'.$name1);
  $this->db->insert('videoss', $save);

Answer (score 0):

```
           $uploaded = $this -> upload -> do_upload('video_image');




            if ($uploaded) {
                if ($data['file_ppt'] != '') {

                    $file = 'uploads/ppt/' . $data['file_ppt'];


                    if (file_exists($file)) {
                        unlink($file);
                    }
                }
            }

        if ($uploaded) {
            $file_ppt = $this -> upload -> data();
            $save['file_ppt'] = $file_ppt['file_name'];
        }



  $this->db->insert('videoss', $save);
```

Comment: sir  iam not understand this one please explain the answer

Comment: You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: controllers/Admin.php

Answer (score 0):

put this in the view  :
                                                                                 
        and in     controller :                                                                                                                                      $names ="";
        $name_array = array();

```
    if(isset($_FILES['file_ppt'])){
    $count = count($_FILES['file_ppt']['size']);
    }else{
    $count=0;
    }

    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
    for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) {
    $_FILES['file_ppt']['name']=md5(time())."".$value['name'][$s];
    $_FILES['file_ppt']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
    $_FILES['file_ppt']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
    $_FILES['file_ppt']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
    $_FILES['file_ppt']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];
            // $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/messages';
            $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
            $config['max_size']    = '200000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $uploaded = $this->upload->do_upload('file_ppt');

    $data = $this->upload->data();

    $names = $names.','.$_FILES['file_ppt']['name'];

            }

       if ($uploaded) {
            // $file_ppt = $this -> upload -> data();
            $save['file_ppt'] = $names;

            // print_r('file ppt'.$file_ppt['file_name']);
        }else {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
```

Comment: <form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Admin/imageupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><label>Video Name</label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter VideoName" class="form-control" name="videoname" id="videoname"><label> Image</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="video_image" id="video_image"> <label>Video Image</label> <input type="file" class="form-control" name="video" id="video"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-t-n-xs" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"   ><strong>Submit</strong></button>

Comment: sir my database SELECT `video_id`, `title`, `url`, `image` FROM `videoss`

Comment: if ($uploaded) {
            $file_ppt = $this -> upload ->data();
            //$save['url'] = $file_ppt['file_name'];
   $save=array(
   'title'=>$this->input->post('videoname'),
   'url'=>$file_ppt['file_name'],
   'image'=>$_FILES['video_image']['name'],
   
   
  );
   
        }
        $file =$_FILES['video_image']['tmp_name'];
         $name1=$_FILES['video_image']['name'];
          $type=$_FILES['video_image']['type'];
         $size=$_FILES['video_image']['size']; move_uploaded_file($file,'./assets/upload/video/'.$name1);  $this->db->insert('videoss', $save);